# Update from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: apt, updates

I'm trying to update from 13.10 to 14.04, but whenever I try to update from terminal by using `sudo apt-get update` I get the error:

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Are you trying to use the Ubuntu upgrade method recommended at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

Answer (score 1):

How to Update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Update is not for upgrading, below are instructions:

Here are instructions to update from 13.10 to 14.04:

Ubuntu Desktops 13.10 to 14.04 (Recommended)

You can easily upgrade over the network with the following procedure.

Run the update-manager application from the Unity Dash or a command line

In Update Manager, click the Settings... button, and enter your password to start the Software Sources application.

Select the sub menu Updates from the Software Sources application.

Confirm the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" option is set to "For any new version", and change it if otherwise.
Close the Software Sources application and return to Update Manager.
In Update Manager, click the Check button to check for new updates.

If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.

A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.
Click Upgrade.

Follow the on-screen instructions.